# Organize workflow in pull requests when two tasks are needed by the third

Tags: git, github, gitlab, workflow, git-workflow

We have a situation where we have 3 tasks to be done. Task 1 and Task 2 are independant from each other and Task 1 and Task 2 are needed in Task 3. How can WE organize workflow with branches and pull requests. If for example we have branches liké that :

main

dev

feat/task-1

feat/task-2

feat/task-3

Developer finishes Task1 and he opens PR1, and finishes Task2 and opens PR2 After that he merges feat/task-1and feat/task-2 into feat/task-3 Finishes Task2 and opens PR3. Reviewer reviews PR1 and PR2 merges them and After that reviews PR3 and merges it. But the question is : how PR1 for example needs work After review ? In PR3 for reviewer he will review also changes of PR1 and PR2 What is the best solution to deal and organize thèse situations.